# Guide/instruction buttons

Tags: buttons, hyperlinks, popup, help, instructions

Can someone tell me the professional name of the buttons that you see when you are in a new page or when it's a new feature?

Those buttons usually open to pop-ups that will guide you in the new page/feature and once you use them they (usually) disappear.

One example would be when Facebook has a new feature they use those kind of buttons along with the new feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think JeromeR has covered quite a few names for the button. We used **"Get me started"** for our website. The particular behaviour is often called **"Web Tour"** or **"Guided Tour"**. Related JS plugin links - [Bootstrap Tour](http://bootstraptour.com/) , [IntroJS](http://usablica.github.io/intro.js/)

Answer (score 2):

The name of that button could be anything appropriate to the users you're addressing. it could be:

- **New here?**
- **Show me**
- **Take a tour**
- **Important**
- **3 quick things**

and so on.

A related question you might want to ask is this: What is the name of this process of welcoming and user-instruction? This concept has a name: first experiences.

### First experiences

Microsoft's guidelines have a section on first experiences that provides a framework for the thing you're indirectly asking about. The guidelines are less about what the button is called and more about when you should provide a first experience, what things you should do, and what things you should avoid, when the user clicks that button or otherwise triggers that early event.

- Have a look: [Windows desktop guidelines on First Experience](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742459.aspx).

I hope that helps you move forward.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. while your answer is really educator still, i remember there is a certain name for those kind of buttons/behaviour, i saw once there even a javascript guide to implement them in your HTML page.

Answer (score 2):

The entire experience of getting users into a new application and familiar with how to use it is referred to as "User Onboarding."

This process can include tutorials, how-to graphics & animations, or buttons & notifications pointing out new features. This is often a first-time/one-time thing, but users can usually access the content through a settings page of some kind indicated by names already suggested in prior answers.

Onboarding also includes the steps to create an account & sign-in to a service, and often continues with communications outside your app/website (email, social media, etc) to get users to come back & continue using your product. Done according to best practices, it's more than simply a "tutorial" button somewhere in the UI.

People may typically think of onboarding new users, but you can use similar techniques to [introduce new features to existing users](http://appcues.com/academy/existing/) as well.

I don't think there's a specific name for any buttons, because there are many ways to accomplish this process that don't involve any buttons at all, and each case would have its unique requirements so being prescriptive may not be helpful.

Here are some resources on how you might approach user onboarding: 
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/08/11/mobile-onboarding-beginners-guide/
https://blog.optimizely.com/2015/01/13/7-tips-to-improve-mobile-app-onboarding/
http://usabilitygeek.com/mobile-app-onboarding-how-to-do-it-right/

Comment: I earned a all new field from my tiny question, thanks a lot guys.